# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Expression[String]?' and 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;

    let userEmailStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringArrayForKey("userEmail");

    let userPasswordStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringArrayForKey("userPassword");

    if(userEmailStored == userEmail) // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Expression[String]?' and 'String?'
    {
        if(userPasswordStored == userPassword) // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Expression[String]?' and 'String?'
        {
            // Login Successfull

           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
           self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        }


    }


}
```

I had a problem as above. What is the solution to the above problems? Thanks

Comment: You are comparing an array with a string. userEmailStored is an array and userEmail is a String. What are you trying to do?

Comment: can you verify `userEmailStored` has any value property or something that can evaluate to a `string` representation of  the actual underlying value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let userEmailStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringArrayForKey("userEmail");
let userPasswordStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringArrayForKey("userPassword");
```

there are error for this two code, the function is `stringForKey`, it is no `stringArrayForKey`. String Array for key is trying to build up string array,
you can not compare a string array with string.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail");
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userPassword");
```

Comment: The problem is solved when replacing stringArrayForKey to stringForKey.
Thanks bro RYANCOAL9999

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a array with  a String.

try:

```
if userEmailStored.contains(userEmail) && userPasswordStored.contains(userPassword) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```